# Cocos2dx Frame Rate Issue on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I am working on a multi platform game using cocos2dx, And I have two categories of assets one for high res devices and one for normal or low res devices. Now issue that I am facing is frame rate on high res devices is low as compare to low res specifically for android. For instance on Samsung S2 it is on average 60 fps but on Samsung S3 it is on average 40 fps. I was assuming that it might be an issue with high res assets then I tried same assets for S3 and S2. Still frame rate on S3 is 40 fps. I don't know why even S3 is faster device as compare to S2.

Any Idea or any suggestion to improve frame rate would be greatly appreciated.

thanx
Ahsan

Comment: Hi Ahsan, did you find the answer to this problem? I have confronted with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy series (i9100, S3 etc.) have a "Power Saving" mode in settings. If you turn this on, the FPS is limited to 30 on all apps. Turning this off can have 60 FPS ....